# set delegate to self but the result is nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I had set my `delegate` to `self` sometimes, just sometimes, the delegate won't set. It is nil. It seems like some memory management issue. I want to know is there any solution to solve this without any memory leak? I will copy my code and my debugging steps in here.

```
func openConversationForPost(_ post: PostViewStructure, viewController: UIViewController) {
    let dest = ChatViewController(service: service, conversationID: post.token!)
    dest.delegate = self
    viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(dest, animated: true)
}
```

[image: Debug Console]

ps1. I know I can use strong but then there will be high risk of crashing.

ps2. The weird thing is when I set the break right on the line where the delegate is being set there is no problem; but, if I let the flow of the programming running normally the delegate is nil.

**Edit**
The init `func` of `ChatViewController`

```
init(service: ServicesProtocol, conversationID: String) {
    self.conversationID = conversationID
    super.init(service: service)
    defer { conversation = DataProvider().object(ChatConversation.self, key: conversationID) }
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the break point ?

Comment: Can you share the `init(_:viewController:)` method being used to initialize **ChatViewController**?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini after setting the delegate

Comment: @DV I edited the question and put the function there.

Comment: @matt self is 'ChatFlowController' and the dest id 'ChatViewController'

Comment: @matt Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182223/discussion-between-tara-tandel-and-matt).